# ng2-table how to add style to specific row

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

Hi I'm new with angular 2. I'm using [ng2-table](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table). I added to my website table like [this](http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/).
I need to add a color to specific **row** inside the table. How is that possible ? 
I tried to add it like the [tutorial](http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/) did with his columns but without success.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @dreamhunter the code is exactly like the code in the tutorial: http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer, taken from here:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/issues/342

We can change te color of the row by adding some style to it like this:

A quick and dirty solution:

Step 1: Integrate jQuery

Step 2: Give your result table an ID like:

```
<ng-table id="resultDataTable" ...
```

Step 3: Modify your onCellClick method:

```
onCellClick(data: any): any {
/* get index of row */
let index = this.tableData.indexOf(data.row);  

/* add an class 'active' on click */
$('#resultDataTable').on('click', 'tr', function (event: any) {
  //noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedFunction
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check their [style file](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/blob/master/demo/assets/css/style.css) provided to know what css-class Names are using and try to override them:

E.g. of classes used: `table` `dataTable` `table-striped` `table-bordered`

*CSS*:

```
table.dataTable tbody th, table.dataTable tbody td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

*Reulsts*:
[image]

Comment: but how to i add css-class to the **rows** ?

Comment: where do i use the classes ? 
This exmple of row from the tutorial:
    {
        'name': 'Victoria Cantrell',
        'position': 'Integer Corporation',
        'office': 'Croatia',
        'ext': '0839',
        'startDate': '2015/08/19',
        'salary': 208.178
    }
where do I use the class to apply it on this row for example ?

Comment: thanks! but I meant how to apply it on specific row ?

Comment: But the tutorial you mentioned didn't achieve this and **your question is not saying you want to style specific row**, i suggest you to update your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131682/discussion-between-faouzi-oudouh-and-groundins).